# How to sweep a bc1... bitcoin segwit address using a mobile app?

Tags: segregated-witness, bitcoin-wallet-app, android, mobile, sweep

I have a bitcoin private key with some money on the segwit bc1 address, but when I try to sweep this private key using mycellium android wallet, it shows up as a 3... address. What other mobile app lets me sweep a bc1 segwit address?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78704/can-you-retrieve-funds-send-to-a-legacy-address-created-with-a-segwit-extended-p

Comment: @UgamKamat No, it's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bitcoin Wallet ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.schildbach.wallet/), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet)) to sweep a paper wallet, including its bc1 (Bech32) address.